# Can pass null to generic function when type is a value type

Tags: vb.net, generics, .net-4.0

I am currently restricted to using VB.NET using .NET 4.0 and I'd like to use a pre-pending function when I make LINQ queries, here is the function I've created:

```
    <Extension>
    Public Iterator Function Prepend(Of TSource)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), item As TSource) As IEnumerable(Of TSource)
        If source Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(source))

        Yield item
        For Each sourceItem In source
            Yield sourceItem
        Next
    End Function
```

But the interesting thing is when you pass a null reference when the function is typed to a value type, say Integer:

```
Dim arr = {1, 2, 3}
Dim arr2 = arr.Prepend(Nothing).ToArray()
```

This produces an array containing: 0, 1, 2, 3. When converted to the equivalent C# and used in a .NET Core 2.1 project, I correctly receive a compiler error telling me I cannot convert between null and an integer.

Is there a way to tell VB.NET that I do not want this sort of thing to happen and cause an error at compile time or will I need to resort to run-time type checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nothing` in VB is not the same as `null` in C#.  The better equivalent is `default`, because it represents the default value for its type.  The behavior is the same for reference types (whose default is a null reference) but very different for value types as you note.

Since this is part of the design of the language, there is no way to turn it off.

Also see Anthony Green's write-up here: https://anthonydgreen.net/2019/02/12/exhausting-list-of-differences-between-vb-net-c/#46

Comment: I see, I will need to be more careful in my use of `Nothing` in the future! Thanks for the link, it will come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting link. Upvote for that link.